# Caliburn.Micro screen transition via conductor

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a **Caliburn.Micro** shell (i.e., an empty *XAML* view to contain other views) rendered by a **Conductor** *ViewModel*. From there I open a **Screen** via:

```
ActivateItem(...)
```

Usually from the newly displayed dialog the user can perform some operations and click buttons (*OK*, *Cancel*, *Build*....) which should each transition to another *screen* (in the shell).

```
public MyDialog : Screen
{
    public void Ok()
    {
        // TODO: Somehow tell the conductor or called of this class about this action.
    }
}
```

What are good ways to achieve these kind of dialog action/message screen transitions?

- Simple *.NET events* are possible -- Wouldn't that be a bad idea?
- CM *`IEventAggregator`* should also work by changing the view
- Checking from the shell Conductor the ViewModel *result* once it has been closed via `TryClose()` -- Should be possible, just don't know how to achieve this in CM.
- *Reference the shell* Conductor instance from that screen (via IoC or directly) -- That seems strong coupling.

Could you please advise.

Comment: Found a good article describing how to use `IEventAggregator`: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach is to use the EventAggregator to facilitate messaging between VMs.

This works especially well when you have multiple windows which are listening for a certain type of event (e.g. a Visual Studio style interface with multiple tool windows which may show context sensitive properties), however it sounds a little overkill for this implementation. Of course the advantages are still a good loose coupling between VMs and a lack of events (which is a good thing!)

It sounds like you want a modal dialog to popup and present an option, and then activate another screen once the first one has returned.

You can attach an event handler to the `Deactivated` event in the child VM which will fire when an item deactivates. It also passes a boolean in the arguments to notify if the item which deactivated was closed - you can check for this and activate the corresponding screen in your conductor.

e.g.

```
this.Deactivated += new EventHandler<DeactivationEventArgs>(WorkspaceViewModel_Deactivated);

void WorkspaceViewModel_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.WasClosed) // raise some event
}
```

Then pass an event up to the conductor, I wouldn't really go the event route for this. This couples the VMs one-way so it may not be the most flexible solution

The alternative is to fire a message via the event aggregator to tell the conductor it needs to open a different window when the child VM closes. The same method can be used but it's decoupled

```
this.Deactivated += new EventHandler<DeactivationEventArgs>(WorkspaceViewModel_Deactivated);

void WorkspaceViewModel_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.WasClosed) MainConductor.EventAggregator.Publish(new ActivateWindowMessage(typeof(SomeVM));
}
```

Comment: You're right about my goal. I'll try the EventAggregator in my "Ok" method once I found how to create that EventAggregator. Also I find it strange for that VM to depend on the Shell/Main Conductor. Should be only the other way around.

Comment: It is, the vm should just take care of itself and the shell should take care of showing the appropriate view, the child vm should dictate what the parent vm should do by messaging but in an indirect fashion so as not to couple the two. I might have written a confusing post!

Comment: No no it's fine, I was more looking at which of my solutions are usually seen better, why, and if possible how to implement. I've used the way the article did by constructor injection of the IEvAgg so that they are not coupled tightly.

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't include any IoC concepts in my answer. The aggregator in CM has quite a natural implementation (interface based), glad you sorted it!